# Finding every nth X-day of the month using PHP, will it always be correct?

Tags: php, date

OK, I've put together some code which, in this particular case, finds the second (2nd) Sunday of every month depending on whether or not you're before or after it (specifically at 5:00PM that day).

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    for( $i = 1 ; $i <=30 ; $i++ )//30 is much more than is needed
    {
        $date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s',date('Y-m-').$i.' 17:00:00');
        if( $date->format('D') == 'Sun' )
        {
            $count++;
        }
        if( $count == 2 )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    $count = 0;
    if( date('Y-m-d H:i:s') > $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') )
    {
        for( $i = 1 ; $i <=30 ; $i++ )
        {
            $date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s',date('Y-').(string)(((int)date('n')+1)%12).'-'.$i.' 17:00:00');
            if( $date->format('D') == 'Sun' )
            {
                $count++;
            }
            if( $count == 2 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        echo $date->format('F jS, Y');
    }
    else
    {
        echo $date->format('F jS, Y');
    }
?>
```

So if you are at the green star it will display August 14, and if you're at the blue star it will display September 11:

[image]

My question is will this always be correct indefinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$date = new DateTime( 'second sunday of this month, 17:00' );
if( date_create()->diff( $date )->invert )
{
    $date = new DateTime( 'second sunday of next month, 17:00' );
}
```

To retrieve second sunday of this month... just pass “second sunday of this month” to [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), then, if the date is in the past ([`DateInterval->invert`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.invert) return 1 if the interval is negative, 0 otherwise), you can retrieve second sunday of next month.

Comment: Wow... I did not know this existed... Very powerful. However, let me ask you something, does it take care of the "exceptional situations" as was mentioned in @PetrHejda 's answer?

Comment: Yes, on Dec, 15 your date will be set to second sunday of next year's January.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems all right. But you don't even need to use all the string comparison and loops. Just pass an argument like "Second Sunday of 2016-04, 17:00" to [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and then check whether the date has passed or not.

Strtotime() takes care of all the exceptional situations like leap-year, next month being Janury of the next year, etc.

```
$currentMonthSecondSunday = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( 'Second Sunday of ' . date( 'Y-m' ) . ', 17:00' ) );
$currentDate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
if ( $currentDate < $currentMonthSecondSunday ) {
    echo $currentMonthSecondSunday;
} else {
    $nextMonthSecondSunday = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( 'Second Sunday of ' . date( 'Y-m', strtotime( 'next month' ) ) . ', 17:00' ) );
    echo $nextMonthSecondSunday;
}
```